Can you destroy a spiritual weapon?
Scenario: I'm attacking with a spiritual weapon, someone else casts sunbeam in a way that it hits the spiritual weapon. Does this destroy the spiritual weapon?

Somewhat related: Will a Disintegrate spell instantly destroy a Spiritual Weapon?, Can you use the Spiritual Weapon spell as a platform, to fly?, Can the Spiritual Weapon spell be used as cover?

In what situation did that question arise? What research have you done yourself on this? What did you learn from similar questions? What do you think happens and why? What part of those spells' descriptions makes you think that way? How do you think the general rules of the game apply in those to those cases? These are the kinds of things you should ask yourself before posting a question and provide your thought process of that with the question. Otherwise all of us are asked by the site to downvote your question because it, as the downvote button states "does not show any research effort".


Someone else casts sunbeam in a way that it hits the spiritual weapon. Does this destroy the spiritual weapon?

The spiritual weapon is a spell effect, and does not have statistics that allow it to be attacked or damaged. Spells that do that, or do have specific counter effects will call that out in a spell description. For example Daylight can dismiss lower level Darkness spells. Or Unseen Servant can be destroyed by hitting it because it has AC and hitpoints.
In general, being caught in the area of another spell's damage effect will not impact a Spiritual Weapon.
Some spells do have effects that can dismiss, dispel or otherwise interact with other spells generically. Dispel Magic would usually dismiss a Spiritual Weapon (depends whether the Spiritual Weapon had been cast at a higher level). When that is the case, the general capabilities of the second spell - how it affects spells being cast or already in effect - will be noted in that spell.
The usual way to resolve this is to look at the text of both spells, and unless there is a description in one of them that could explain how there could be an interaction between the spells, then there isn't. Most spells don't really interact, they just have their effects on areas and targets at the same time.

They might have more luck attacking the darkness.https://youtu.be/-leYc4oC83E?t=90
